# TCP Socket receiving and processing multiple messages

Tags: java, database, sockets, tcp

I'm having some troubles in getting all the data coming from a TCP socket.

In my server, I'm reading data from a socket like that:

```
        int len;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2000];
        try {
            this.in = new DataInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());
            this.out = new DataOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
            running = true;

            while (running) {
                len = in.read(buffer);
                if (len < 0) {
                    running = false;
                } else {
                    parsePacket(buffer, len);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Catch IOException: " + ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                System.out.println("Closing");
                in.close();
                out.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Finally IOException: " + ex);
            }
        }
```

The packet format is like that:

**[HEADER][DATA][TERMINATOR]**

- Header --> sequence of characters that identifies the start of the message (no info about length of the packet);
- Data --> Is divided in segments, like: **[Size Seg. 1][Data Seg. 1][Size Seg. 2][Data Seg. 2][Size Seg. 3][Data Seg. 3]....[Size Seg. N][Data Seg. N]**
- Terminator --> [0x00]

The data are received very fast (sometimes 200ms or less), so sometimes the `read(buffer)` fills the `buffer` with messages like:

- [HEADER1][DATA1][TERM1] or,
- [HEADER1][DATA1][TERM1][HEADER2][DATA2][TERM2].............[HEADER N][DATA N][TERM N] or,
- [HEADER1][DATA1][TERM1][HEADER2][DATA2][TERM2].............[HEADER N][DAT (last message incomplete)

The `parsePacket()` method is able to parse a message with the above format and if it has more messages next, they will be parsed also (recursively). But it will not parse the last message if it is incomplete (I don't want that, but I didn't find a suitable solution until now).

The data coming inside the messages are stored in a MySQL database (using JDBC driver). Each parse of a message can involve multiple queries to the database. As I'm using just one thread to receive, parse and store the data, the execution of the code is not as fast as it should... The data should be received and stored as quickly as possible.

Some points that I would like to discuss:

- What could be the best approach to get all the messages without lose some of them?
- How could I improve the way that the data is received and stored? (The data should be stored as quickly as possible!)

Comment: Remember that TCP is a _streaming_ protocol, not a packet protocol. This means that you might not get all of a message in one receive call, or you may get more that one message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As TCP is already a stream protocol the simplest way to read this data is as a stream. I would add a listener to process the events.

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));

try {
   while(true) {
       listener.startOfMessage();
       for(int segSize; (segSize = dis.readInt()) > 0;) {
          byte[] bytes = new byte[segSize];
          dis.readFully(bytes);
          listener.data(bytes);
       }
       int footer = dis.read();
       // check footer ??
       listener.endOfMessage();
   }
} catch(EOFException endOfStream) {
   // handle or ignore
} finally {
   // close everything.
}
```

When you do the buffering yourself, you have to also re-assemble the messages and retain incomplete messages which is allot of headache for no benefit here.

> The data are received very fast (sometimes 200ms or less)

200 ms is about 600,000,000 clock cycles for every CPU you have.  This is an eternity to a computer. :)

The code above should handle in the order of 20,000 messages in 200 ms.  If you needed more than this you could use NIO instead, but I wouldn't assume you need to.

> The data should be stored as quickly as possible!

I suspect that MySQL is fine, it is not "as quickly as possible" but I don't see any reason in what you have said not to use it.

Comment: But one of the problem that I'm seeing with this solution is that I'm not able to get the length of the message at the beginning of the message...

Comment: In that case you have to parse the message.  You have to determine whether you have a size or a terminator next. (See my changes for a simple example)

Comment: I'm trying this approach but I'm using wireshark to see when the messages are received by the server application, and I see a huge delay between the instant that the message with a specific set of data is received by the application and the instant in which the same dataset is stored in the database... I'm printing the duration time from the instant of the message start and the instant that the message is fully parsed (and data stored). Sometimes I'm getting times like 1 or 2 seconds... Which is too long. I remind that I'm doing all of that in a single thread. Any suggestion?

Comment: A single thread shouldn't be a problem. Can you try just logging the SQL you would produce but without touching the database to see how long it takes in Java?

Comment: Without making any query to database, I'm getting 400ms (max), but most of the messages are between ~100ms and ~200ms. To get the time I'm using a code like: `startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //build message and parse it; endTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); print(endTime-startTime);`

Comment: Have you warmed up the JVM?  Before processing the data from the connection I would try building and parsing 10,000+ dummy messages to warm up the JVM.  Even so 400 ms is a long time. Did a GC occur at that time.  What is the average?

Comment: Do you mean the average time when I add the warming up process?

Comment: Just some more information: the application has more threads (around 5 or 6)... Some of them are also querying the database...

Comment: The average time when you measure it. A high peak might not be a problem if it happen rarely.  A high average is more likely to be an issue.  Querying the database and updates can slow down each other.  This is why I suggest testing doing everything e..g updates without actually touching the database, to see how much time is spent in Java alone and how much is in the database (The total time - the java time)  This is point you to the one which needs optimising or needs to go faster.

Answer (score 1):

You are producing `String` from `buffer`, right? In this case I suggest you to modify interface of `parsePacket` method and transform loop to something like this:

```
        String tail = "";
        String line = "";
        while (running) {
            len = in.read(buffer);
            if (len < 0) {
                running = false;
            } else {
                line = tail + new String(buffer);
                tail = parsePacket(line, len);
            }
        }
```

in your `parsePacket` you have to cut unterminated tail of line and return it from method.

Comment: Well, change String type to byte[] and use them in this style: `lineBuf = ArrayUtils.addAll(tail, buffer);`

Answer (score 0):

TCP provides a *stream* transport service, not a packet service. To achieve “packetization” protocols have to frame the packets themselves. In your case the framing is achieved with the `[TERMINTAOR]` marker. On the client side what you should do is:

1. Check if your `buffer` contains the marker. If it does not then issue a `read` to add data to your `buffer` and go back to step 1.
2. parse and consume a packet from the buffer
3. back to step 1.

Answer (score -1):

TCP is a streaming protocol. It delivers all the bytes written to the socket on one end to the socket on the other end in the order they are written. It does **not** guarantee that they will arrive in "chunks" that are the same size as they were put in. Reads might get more or less bytes than were written in any given write. But all the bytes are there and they're all in the right order.

The solution to this is to use a protocol which defines message boundaries - either a message terminator, or a length header, or a self-describing format like XML.

Answer (score -1):

TCP is a streaming protocol it does not guarantee the size of the messages from one port to another of same chunk size. upon reading you may get more or less amount of bytes that is written in one write.